# Le « compact » et le pacte ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, étymologie, comparaison-de-langues

Je lis un [article](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/europe/201811/28/01-5205978-litalie-adopte-la-loi-anti-migrants-de-salvini.php) sur entre autres choses le recul de certains états relativement à leur engagement envers le « [Global Compact for Migration](https://refugeesmigrants.un.org/migration-compact) » et la version française donne « [Pacte mondial pour les migrations](https://refugeesmigrants.un.org/fr/pacte-mondial-pour-les-migrations) ». En langue anglaise on a le [*compact*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/compact#etymonline_v_17252) du latin *compactum*, la substantivation du participe passé de forme neutre de *compacisci*, de 1590 pour « an agreement or contract between two or more parties » nous dit-on (Etymonline) ; on trouve le mot directement dans la [Constitution des États-Unis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_One_of_the_United_States_Constitution#Clause_3:_Compact_Clause) par exemple. Par ailleurs comme en français on a aussi le [pacte](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pacte) en langue anglaise ([*pact*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pact)).

On trouve le [compact](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/compact2?idf=dmfXgXpcYrmXcceb;str=0) en français au DmF (aussi [Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/compact1), [FEW](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/60046))  pour « pacte, accord » (DmF) :

> Et par ainsi doncques, quand de rechief et tout de nouvel vit ce point
>   redoublé par le compact de ces jeusnes verdes testes, moult luy en
>   desplut.
>
> [ Chastellain, G., [*Chronique*](https://books.google.com/books?id=6vo1jUkWackC&lpg=PA416&ots=OnfU-CkTKq&dq=%22Et%20par%20ainsi%20doncques%2C%20quand%20de%20rechief%20et%20tout%20de%20nouvel%20vit%20ce%20point%20redoubl%C3%A9%20par%20le%20compact%20de%20ces%20jeusnes%20verdes%20testes%2C%20moult%20luy%20en%20desplut%22&pg=PA416#v=onepage&q=%22Et%20par%20ainsi%20doncques,%20quand%20de%20rechief%20et%20tout%20de%20nouvel%20vit%20ce%20point%20redoubl%C3%A9%20par%20le%20compact%20de%20ces%20jeusnes%20verdes%20testes,%20moult%20luy%20en%20desplut%22&f=false) K., t.4, c.1456-1471, 416 ds.
>   *Dictionnaire du moyen français* ]

- Quand l'emploi de *compact* pour le pacte, l'accord a-t-il cessé ?
- Pourquoi le terme (serait utile en anglais alors qu'il) ne le serait
  pas en français ; quel(s) terme(s) s'est le plus substitué à compact
  quand son emploi a cessé dans les contextes où il était utilisé ?
- Si on avait théoriquement à traduire un texte, une phrase, contenant *pact* et *compact*, comment procéderait-on ?
- Le *pacte* est-il le terme consacré pour exprimer le *compact* dans
  le contexte en question ; ou pourquoi est-il meilleur ici qu'*accord, entente* etc. ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans ma très maigre collection du XVII<sup>e</sup>, je ne trouve *COMPACT* utilisé, au sens d'accord, qu'en référence à deux accords très particuliers. Deux accords passés avec un pape.
Le dictionnaire dit de Trévoux <sup>0</sup> ne connaît pas *compact* mais *COMPACTAT* auquel il donne le sens d'accord mais en précisant expressément : "***Il faut éviter ce mot***"...
Et j'observe enfin que les dictionnaires anglais-français de la même époque traduisent le *compact* anglais par *contrat, accord, convention*... aucun par un *compact* français et très peu par *pacte*.

L'Encyclopédie (fin XVIII<sup>e</sup>) ne trouve elle-même que ces deux cas particuliers pour illustrer l'article correspondant. Allant même jusqu'à préciser qu'il s'agit très spécifiquement des *"accords passés entre le pape et les cardinaux avant l'élection de Paul IV."* (mid XVI<sup>e</sup>)
L'édition contemporaine du Grand Dictionnaire de l'Académie Françoise ignore tout simplement ce mot.

J'aurais donc pour cela, tendance à croire que l'on a cessé d'utiliser ce mot (hors référence explicite aux deux accords précités), dans ce sens <sup>1</sup>, à partir de mi XVIè.

---

Je ne crois pas que sa conservation par l'anglais et son oubli par le français soient gouvernés par une question d'utilité mais, bien plutôt par une question de référence historique.

Les rois de France n'ont, à ma connaissance jamais paraphé de *compact*, la vie du Français n'a jamais, à ma connaissance été réglée par quelque *compact* que ce soit.
 Une bulle ou deux ? Bon... ! Gallicanisme aidant... On les aura vite oubliées... et si, par surcroît,... ses plus grands adversaires... me commandent de ne pas l'utiliser... on pourrait dire l'affaire entendue... à l'unanimité.

Il en va tout autrement pour le Britannique.
Si j'en crois Abel Boyer, "*The english constitution is founded upon an original compact between King and people, which was also the fundation of all Gothicks governments*"
Sans parler des... colonisés. (*Mayflower compact*)

Je crois donc que quand un texte fonde vos droits, vos relations avec le gouvernement... son nom, tous les termes utilisés resteront au contraire très vivants.<sup>2</sup>

---

- Pour ce qui est de la traduction d'un document de l'époque, je ferais confiance à [Abel Boyer.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=z_oPPYcWmfIC&dq=compact%20dictionary&hl=fr&pg=PA131#v=onepage&q=compact%20dictionary&f=false) (*contrat, accord, convention*)
- Pour ce qui est de la traduction du très contemporain *Global compact for Migration* et, relativement à ce que représente le document, j'aurais, à la différence des auteurs de la version française, fait confiance au très officiel [Vocabulaire des relations internationales](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjxqai81I7fAhVSzIUKHd9ID7Q4ChAWMAB6BAgEEAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.culture.gouv.fr%2Fcontent%2Fdownload%2F103335%2F1217334%2Ffile%2Fvocabulaire_2014_relations-int.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3h6_gDdSBHlU5-E_agw0XS) et donc parlé d' *Accord global*. Mais évidemment... ça en jette moins côté solennité...

---

Ce qui répond indirectement à votre dernière question : Non!, *pacte* n'est pas, pour moi, la meilleure traduction. D'abord, je ne l'ai que très rarement rencontrée dans les dictionnaires des XVI<sup>e</sup>-XVII<sup>e</sup> et ensuite parce que je tiens *accord* pour la *meilleure-pour-moi*... en raison du fait qu'il s'agit du terme retenu par le JORF en pareille circonstance et que... j'aime être cohérent.
Après, peut-être était-il entendu qu'il convenait là de faire passer un message ... de paix.

<sub>0 : Je le classe dans le XVII<sup>e</sup> car, bien que rédigé au siècle suivant, il s'agit d'une compilation des dicos du XVII<sup>e</sup>. (Sous la direction de Jésuites... on appréciera d'autant l'interdiction...)</sub>

<sub>1 : En ce contexte car au sens d'accord entre systèmes, principes, conclusion de discussions philosophiques, sens que *compact* possédait aussi, on a très vite (voire encore plus tôt) préféré lui substituer : *synthèse*.</sub>

<sub>2 : Quand ces termes n'acquièrent pas automatiquement le statut de symboles. Si, ici, je vous dis : *Déclaration des*..., je suis sûr de la façon dont 90% des Français rempliront les points de suspension.</sub>

<sub>NDaCOSwt-1 : Et je présume que l'on aura profité de cette disparition du lexique pour donner à l'adjectif autrefois invariable en genre, *COMPACTE*, (au sens qu'on lui connait aujourd'hui) un masculin différent de son féminin.</sub>

---

<sub>NDaCOSwt-2 : Un commentaire de Saint-Jacques m'invitait à m'interroger sur l'impact que pourrait avoir la contrainte, le fait que l'accord soit ou non contraignant sur la traduction proposée à *compact*.</sub>
<sub>J'ai répondu rapidement et a priori non en me basant sur une simple logique : S'il y a *accord* entre des parties c'est bien qu'auparavant il y avait *conflit* entre ces parties. Positions conflictuelles. Quiconque a un jour vécu un conflit (même personnel) sait bien qu'un *accord* ne peut survenir qu'à la condition que chacune des parties... mette de l'eau dans son vin. C'est bien a dire que chaque partie fasse des concessions, accepte donc des contraintes. Je crois donc la *contrainte* comme inhérente à l'*accord*. Un *accord* est nécessairement *contraignant*.</sub>
<sub>Si un accord n'est pas contraignant pour une des parties alors on ne parlera plus d'*accord* mais d'***édit***, de **traité**, certains peut-être même de *diktat*. Mais... dans ce cas... même les anglo-saxons ne parleront plus de *compact*.</sub>

---

<sub>NDaCOSwt-3 Au fil de l'aiguille cousant ma note 2, je réalise toutefois un tout autre problème susceptible de me faire revoir ma position. Gros **B-mol** donc :</sub>
<sub>Dans ma note précédente, je considère un accord passé entre X,Y et Z **relativement** à X,Y et Z, Concernant X,Y et Z, engageant X,Y et Z, entre eux et surtout **pour eux**.</sub>
<sub>Il se trouve ici que nous sommes dans un cas ou X,Y et Z vont s'engager quasi-unilatéralement **au profit** d'un T non partie prenante, non signataire et en cela, non engagé lui-même. Ça c'est une distinction importante à mes yeux.</sub> 
<sub>Que ce soit au profit de ou au détriment de, ce genre de *compact*, (en anglais dans le texte) on connaît bien depuis au moins... Strasbourg... 847... il porte le nom de ***serment.*** Peut être a-t-on jugé ce mot un poil *old-school*. Et peut-être alors, se référant au [sens B du TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pacte), lui a-t-on préféré *pacte*.</sub>
<sub>Choisir *pacte* n'est pas absurde donc, mais, je, d'aussi loin que je suis ici& maintenant concerné, ne suivrai néanmoins pas, le TLF donnant à cette acception la définition *d'accord constant*. J'en reviens donc à *accord*</sub>

Comment: @Saint-Jacques : Pour ce qui est de l'impact de la contrainte je vous promets d'y réfléchir. A priori, ici maintenant, je répondrais par la négative. Pour le JORF, je vous présente mes excuses pour cet acronyme très, voir exclusivement hexagonal puisqu'il s'agit du *Journal Officiel de la République Française* qu'on a ici coutume d'abréger ainsi car... in extenso... c'est vraiment trop long. Tellement que l'on finit même par abréger l'acronyme en JO. Mais pardon encore, je comprends parfaitement que cela n'ait pas de sens pour vous.

Comment: @Saint-Jacques : Pour le NDaCOSwt, ce n'est qu'une bien banale extension des NDA / NDE / NDT que l'on peut retrouver dans les notes de bas de page de certains travaux pour distinguer les Notes D e l'Auteur / e l'Éditeur /u  Traducteur. Vieille habitude prise à l'occasion de travaux collectifs, ce que sont les réponses ici. NDaCOSwt = Note De aCOSwt donc. Rien de plus.

Comment: Merci de ces précisions. Incidemment est-ce bien le _Journal_ en question qui retient ou s'il constate ce qui est retenu etc. Oui la note 2 bien je me suis demandé s'il en serait de même pour les quatre attributs à l'article 1 de la Constitution. Mais les mots _droits_, _hommes_ ou _citoyens_ ne sont pas utilisés avec une acception différente de l'usuel. Mais considérez ces [commentaires](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/24938?m=47910043#47910043) de locuteurs de langue anglaise sur l'emploi du _compact_, il n'est pas même certain que ce soit couramment entendu. Bien intéressant !

Comment: Notez que le dictionnaire de Boyer rend l'extrait du _original compact_ par _contrat originel_ ; j'ai aussi noté que l'_accord global_ au Vocabulaire des rel. int. vaut semblet-t-il pour les équivalents _global agreement, package, package deal_ en collocation. Si hypothétiquement le compact était non-contraignant dans le domaine en question, réévalueriez-vous votre choix ? Pour une perspective sur le lexique juridique voir aussi [ceci](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/34084/2822), [ceci](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/34082/2822) ou [ceci](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/33962/2822). Merci !

Comment: @Saint-Jacques : En réponse au côté contraignant, j'ai augmenté la réponse de deux notes (-2 et -3). Le JORF ni ne retient ni ne constate ce qui est retenu. Le JORF dit! Il dit la Loi. C'est le Français qui doit accepter/retenir ce que le JORF dit. Avec et dans les mots employés, mots dont la signification est donnée dans ce même journal puisqu'il publie aussi les fascicules du DAF.

Comment: Merci ! Un bel effort, la réponse répond, est intéressante, nuancée et bien présentée. Comme on sait donc qu'autant les textes fondateurs américains et britanniques ont la référence au _compact_, on peut penser que ça reste dans l'usage, pas vraiment à mon avis, mais je pense que ça peut avoir eu une influence certaine pour le nom du pacte sur les migrations pour des juristes anglophones, peut-être que ça se veut un truc fondateur dans le domaine etc. C'est pas le sujet mais il ne fait aucun doute qu'il soit non-contraignant alors cet aspect-là ne les a pas empêché de faire ce choix lexical.